# ssh - "Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" - using password

Tags: ssh, centos, accounts

I attempted to create an new user account that I wish to use to log in using ssh.

I did this (in CentOs):

```
/usr/sbin/adduser -d /home/testaccount -s /bin/bash user
passwd testaccount
```

This is the error I receive when trying to log in via ssh:

```
~/.ssh$ ssh -v testaccount@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
testaccount@xxx's password: 
Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The "connection closed" message appeared immediately after entering the password
(if I enter the wrong password it waits and then prompts for another password)

I am able to log in from the same computer using other accounts that had been setup previously.

When logged into the remote machine I am able to do 'su testaccount'

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please try with a command like `ssh -v testaccount@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /bin/sh` and tell us if there's something different.

Comment: I tried adding the /bin/sh to the end of the command, but I got the messages as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add this line to `/etc/security/ssh_users`:

```
+:testaccount:ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

The last message seems to indicate that you're using kerberos and that the failure was on the kerberos side. Do you have any more information, for instance, in /var/log/auth.log or other kerberos related files?

Comment: /var/log/auth.log doesn't exist. According to the kerberos config at /usr/krb5.conf, the log file is at /var/log/krb5libs.log, but that doesn't exist either. Thanks for you help.